# json_encode must cast object as array

Tags: php, json

Currently I need to build an API to output as json format, and what I currently do (as example) is the following:

```
$array=array();
$array['firstname']="John";
$array['lastname']="Doe";
$array['cities']=array();
$array['cities']['name']=array("London","Brighton");
$array['cities']['population']=array("12000000","500000");
echo json_encode($array);
```

The output is:

> {"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","cities":{"name":["London","Brighton"],"population":["12000000","500000"]}}

However I was told that this is incorrect, and the output needs to be

> {"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","cities":**[**{"name":["London","Brighton"],"population":["12000000","500000"]}**]**}

(note the square brackets in the output). The reason was claimed that cities itself needs to be specified as an array since $array['cities'] is an array.

My questions are:

1) Is it custom to add square brackets in these cases to indicate it is an array?

2) How can I change my php code in order to have these square-brackets in the output?

help appreciated

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's what the output needs to be? I'd expect London and Brighton (and their respective populations) to be in separate objects in the `cities` array.

Comment: Hi, I was surprised too, but was asked if I could change it to the 'correct' format, by having it in square-brackets. My understanding is that key-value arrays are always objects in javascript, but since cities[] itself is an array, it needs to be casted as such.

Comment: I think they will tell you it's wrong, but https://3v4l.org/KeZOh

Comment: that does the trick yes ...:)

Answer (score 1):

It's here

```
$array=array();
$array['firstname']="John";
$array['lastname']="Doe";
$array['cities']=array();
$array['cities'][]=array(
                        'name'=>array("London","Brighton"),
                        'population'=>array("12000000","500000")
                   );
echo json_encode($array);
```